# Unsatisfiable constraints with NSTableView when calling reloadData

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, osx-mountain-lion, autolayout

I have a view-based NSTableView with the table view's NSTableCellView's setup graphically through interface builder in the latest version of Xcode on 10.8.2.

When I call -reloadData on the NSTableView, it crashes with:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x105cb8bf0 h=--& v=--& V:[NSTableRowView:0x105ca7020(0)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10596aa30 h=--& v=-&- V:[GroupTableRowView]-(2)-|   (Names: GroupTableRowView:0x100185860, '|':NSTableRowView:0x105ca7020 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1058d9770 h=--& v=-&- V:|-(1)-[GroupTableRowView]   (Names: GroupTableRowView:0x100185860, '|':NSTableRowView:0x105ca7020 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10596aa30 h=--& v=-&- V:[GroupTableRowView]-(2)-|   (Names: GroupTableRowView:0x100185860, '|':NSTableRowView:0x105ca7020 )>
```

I can't turn off auto-resizing mask translation on any of the views involved as their constraints are managed by the NSTableView. It's clear that the constraints are conflicting because the NSTableRowView can't possibly have a 0 height while still satisfying the other two constraints on the GroupTableRowView that specify mandatory padding between the superview (the row view?). I'm not sure how to resolve this, any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Update**:
I found a workaround. The issue is that for some reason the NSTableRowView was being sent a frame size of `{0, 0}` when calling -reloadData on the table view. I overrode `-setFrameSize:` in the NSTableRowView subclass and only pass the message up the responder chain when the size is not `{0,0}`.

```
- (void)setFrameSize:(NSSize)newSize
{
    if (!NSEqualSizes(newSize, NSZeroSize))
        [super setFrameSize:newSize];
}
```

To use the subclass, implement NSTableViewDelegate's [-tableView:rowViewForRow:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView%3arowViewForRow%3a) method to return an instance of the custom subclass.

```
- (NSTableRowView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView rowViewForRow:(NSInteger)row
{
    id rowView = [[GroupTableRowView alloc] init];
    // configure any custom properties
    return rowView;
}
```

If the table view is designed entirely in IB, you can simply drag a new NSView into your table view and set it's custom class to your NSTableRowView subclass and change it's User Interface Item Identifier to `NSTableViewRowViewKey`

Comment: Bump. I have run into a similar problems when using view based table views. Did you make any progress on your problem?

Comment: I updated my question with a workaround. I'm still looking for why the NSTableCellView is being sent `{0,0}` but I can't reproduce this in a demo app to submit with a bug report to Apple.

Comment: @Andrew I think this is actually the solution, thanks for this!

Comment: @Andrew, thanks for posting this. I had the exact same issue. It was driving me crazy and I don't think I would have figured this out.

Comment: @Andrew, Can you post how you subclass  your tablerowview? I didn't use any tablerowview but this problem occurs!

Comment: @Andrew, Oh I see. It's category, not subclassing

Comment: It's a subclass, typically you want to avoid using a category to override an existing method, especially one in code you don't own. I've updated my answer showing how to tell the table view to use your custom row view.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it always drove me nuts..

I've solved it using your code, but subclassing `NSTableRowView` instead of `NSTableCellView`. To automatically let the table use your custom row view, add a custom `NSView` into your table. Set its class to your custom row view and, important, its identifier to `NSTableViewRowViewKey`.

With this special identifier, the table automatically uses it as a row view.

Comment: You're right, I went back and looked at my code and I am actually subclassing NSTableRowView. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but with column width rather than row height. Unsatisfiable autolayout constraints were popping up on the cells of view-based `NSTableView`s immediately after `reloadData` was called. In my case, it was caused by the minimum width setting on the `NSTableColumn` being too small to contain the minimum width for the constraints in the cell. So for anyone with a similar problem, I would first verify that.

The "interesting" part was that this was only an issue for `reloadData`, not for normal layout, because there were constraints on the width of the `NSTableView` that prevented it from normally ever attempting to create a cell that small. But when `reloadData` was called, it apparently first creates a new cell with its frame size set to the minimum column width, before later resizing the column to fit properly (if you have the table set to do that). So even though everything appeared to work fine, it would still spit out the error about unsatisfiable constraints right after `reloadData` was called, because the initial width of the cell view was too small for the padding, etc.

Moral of the story is to always check that the *minimum* `NSTableColumn` width is big enough for the constraints in the cell, even if you don't think the column will ever be that small. IB makes it easy to tinker with the constraints, and it's easy to forget to recheck the column width options after changing something in the cells.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This saved me hours of painful debugging.